# /clr:nostdlib requires that mscorlib.dll be in the list of forced usings

Tags: visual-studio, command-line-interface, clr, intellisense, mscorlib

I am working on a big CLR/CLI project.
It is showing this error in the beginning of every file.
Error Code: 2988

Also, due to this, intellisense in Visual Studio is not working, which is actually my major problem here.

When I open the same VS Solution in VS2015, I don't get this error, and the intellisense works fine.

In VS2017, I got this kind of error (and "not" working intellisense) in few files. I recently tried  VS2019 Preview, and I am getting this error in every file.

But the **project/solution builds fine**. I don't get any error there.

[image]

**Things that I have tried:**
 - Tried changing different options in "Common Runtime Support" option in project properties.

- Tried including `#using <mscorlib.dll>` in the file.
- Tried toggling 'use of precompiled header'
- Cleaning projects and removing .vs folder and also removing VS database from temp folder.

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: I have the same problem. It doesn't affect compilation, but the intellisense error drives me crazy. I've tried the same things you've tried. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Exit Visual Studio, delete the .vs directory on your project/solution and start Visual Studio again. Problem solved.

In my case it was related to opening a copied project as a directory instead of through the .sln file, which started a cmake buildup, which trashed Intellisense. I'm Using VS2022 here.